# Can PHP CLI return immediate results in the terminal window?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm trying to understand how the php cli is supposed to work. Do you have to run everything as a script like:

Filename: helloworld.php

```
<?php
print "Hello World!";
?>
```

followed by:

```
chmod +x helloworld.php
php helloworld.php
```

Or is there a way to have it interact the way python does?

I tried using the `-a` option but am still not getting any results.

Comment: Yes. php helloworld.php is enough , if you set the path . what  error you got ? http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Comment: I wanted to do that to, but didn't find, so i made my own console.class.php wich emulates a php console :)

Comment: 1) PHP scripts don't need to be executable if you pass them as argument to the PHP interpreter 2) The interactive mode expects your EOF signal (Ctrl+D on Unix if I recall correctly) but won't run line by line.

Comment: You mean interact with user? For example wait for user input?

Comment: I'd like to be able to input `true == false;` and see the result.

Comment: @Bob0t I'd love to see your console.class.php. Posted anywhere?

Comment: @MikeiLL actually not, it's a dev version, if you want i'll PM you once it will be fully operational ! it's based on STDIN read and eval ^^

Comment: Yes please do if you remember to, man. Seems surprising there isn't something yet. Maybe just 'cause it's so easy to see results in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak Python but I suppose you're looking for an interactive *console* as, for example, the one found in many JavaScript platforms such as Node:

```
C:\>node
> var x=2, y=3;
undefined
> console.log(x*y);
6
undefined
>
```

As far as I know, PHP does not have such feature. The PHP interpreter needs to parse the complete script before it's able to execute it.

There is an *interactive* mode but it expects a single code block—it isn't a console:

```
C:\>php -a
Interactive mode enabled

C:\>php -a
Interactive mode enabled

<?php
$x=2;
$y=3;
^Z

C:\>php -a
Interactive mode enabled

<?php
echo $x*$y;
^Z

Notice: Undefined variable: y in - on line 2

Call Stack:
    7.7505     355096   1. {main}() -:0


Notice: Undefined variable: x in - on line 2

Call Stack:
    7.7505     355096   1. {main}() -:0

0
C:\>
```

---

> I'd like to be able to input true == false; and see the result.

The closest you can get is `-r`:

```
C:\>php -r "var_dump(true == false);"
bool(false)
```

Don't forget shell escaping rules.

Comment: I get as far as `Interactive mode enabled`, but entering `<?php echo $x*$y;` followed by `^Z` (or `^C`) only yields `[3]+ Stopped php -a`

Comment: You run `chmod +x` so you must be using some Unix. I believe the short-cut for you is `Ctrl+D` (`Ctrl+Z` sends to background).

Comment: yes! `ctrl-d` - "ends text input for many UNIX programs". It's still not outputting the same useful output like `Call Stack` and `Notice`. Referencing undefined variables just gives `0`. Confirmed undefined by `print_r(get_defined_vars())`.

Comment: Regular error reporting directives still apply. I also have Xdebug installed.

Comment: Yes. I noticed the errors had shown up in my log. Looks like it's time to install Xdebug as well. Thanks again, man.